# Clicking a button in an HTML page using CGI C++

Tags: c++, cgi

I have an HTML page in CGI C++. How can I output the text in h1(id="h1_id") that was entered in input(input type="text") when clicking the button?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout<<"Content-type:text/html \n\n";
    cout<<"<html>\n";
    cout<<"<head>\n";
    cout<<"<title>First CGI WEB-program</title>\n";
    cout<<"<rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"Source Files/style.css\">";
    cout<<"</head>\n";

    cout<<"<body>\n";
    cout<<"<h1 id=\"h1_id\">You entered: </h1>\n";

    cout<<"<form method=\"GET\">\n";
    cout<<"<input type=\"text\">\n";
    cout<<"<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Click\">\n";
    cout<<"</form>\n";
    cout<<"</body>\n";

    cout<<"</html>\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program does not take any different action depending on what the client is requesting. When it loads a page, the server will likely get a `GET /` request.

You probably need to give a name to your form inputs, so that it is possible to identify them when reading the values. For example:

```
<input type="text" name="formvalue">
```

When you submit the form, it will either get a `GET` or a `POST` depending on the submit action. In your case it will perform a `GET`, so you will need to look for the form data in your URL as parameters. See [html forms in w3cschools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp).

For example, you would receive a `GET /?formvalue=hello` if you click the submit button with the text *hello* in the text input.

Then, you need to handle this case in the server logic. Some pseudocode:

```
if (request.parameters.contains("formvalue")) {
   std::string value = request.get
   cout << R"(<h1 id="h1_id">You entered: )" << request.parameters.get("formvalue") << "</h1>\n";
}
```

One thing you should probably consider is to use a C/C++ library that implements the CGI bits for you. See [question tagged with fastcgi and c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fastcgi%20c%2b%2b). There are also HTTP libraries that help you deal with the protocol specifics (parsing URLs, parsing HTTP headers, etc.).

I highly recommend you to use a packet sniffer such as Wireshark to see requests and replies between your server and your client.